# How to "before do" every other route except a couple ?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Ok, here is the deal. I need to do a check whether the user is logged in before every get or post request, except the login, signup and home route.

Right now, i have the below code on every route i want checked.

```
redirect '/' if !check_login?
```

I checked the docs for a way to do this, so far i got only this and it didn't work.

```
before do, except => ['/','/login','/signup']
   if request.request_method == "POST"
        redirect '/' if !check_login?
   end
end
```

Any way to get this done? Please let me know.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong it would be `before except => ['/','/login','/signup'] do ...` — but there is no `except` condition. What docs were you looking at that had that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead route:

```
before %r{^(?!(/|/login|/signup)$)} do
   if request.request_method == "POST"
        redirect '/' if !check_login?
   end
end
```

This will match every route except `/`, `/login`, and `/signup`.